# How do I handle form data in aiohttp responses

Tags: python, multipartform-data, python-3.5, aiohttp

I'm looking to get the multipart form data and turn it into a dictionary. Easy enough for json, but this seems to be a bit different.

Current code:

```
app = web.Application()

async def deploy(request):
    # retrieve multipart form data or
    # x-www-form-urlencoded data
    # convert to a dictionary if not already
    text = "Hello"
    return web.Response(text=text)
app.router.add_post('/', deploy)

web.run_app(app)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `request.post()` method.

```
app = web.Application()

async def deploy(request):
    # retrieve multipart form data or
    # x-www-form-urlencoded data
    data = await request.post()
    print(data)
    text = "Hello"
    return web.Response(text=text)

app.router.add_post('/', deploy)

web.run_app(app)
```

Comment: Awesome. Docs for aiohttp is a little thin on examples. I hope this helps someone in the future.